# Read float and insert to an array of const char *

Tags: c++, arrays, char

From a text file, I read several values like

```
const float vLowCut   = cfg.get<float>("LowCut");
const float vLowCut1   = cfg.get<float>("LowCut1");
...
```

How would it be possible to append those in a const char array ie like

```
const char * CutList[2] = {"value"+vLowCut, "value2"+vLowCut2)
```

Of course the above line does not work, just wanted to demonstrate what I want to have.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use "value"+to_string (vLowCut)  ?

Comment: Yes, it returns 
`cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'const char*' in initialization`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be difficult to use `const char *` here, since you'd need to create an array for it to point to. A C++ idiom would be more convenient:

```
std::string CutList[2] = {
    "value" + std::to_string(vLowCut),
    "value2" + std::to_string(vLowCut2)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Us the [`to_string()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) function like this:

```
std::string CutList = {"value: "+ std::to_string(vLowCut), " value2: " + std::to_string(vLowCut2))
```

Comment: You can't initialise a `const char *` from a temporary `std::string` object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? You can do that with `std::to_string`:

```
std::string CutList[2] = {"value" + std::to_string(vLowCut), 
                          "value2" + std::to_string(vLowCut2));
```

If you want to use explicit format specifiers, you may use std::stringstream instead i.e. like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

auto my_float_to_string = 
   [](float f){ std::stringstream ss; 
                ss << std::setprecision(3) << f;
                return ss.str(); };
std::string CutList[2] = {"value" + my_float_to_string(vLowCut), 
                          "value2" + my_float_to_string(vLowCut2));
```

You may use `c_str()` to convert it back to `const char*`:

```
strstr(CutList[0].c_str());
```

But do not use `c_str()` as a permanent storage, it will be destroyed once `std::string` object was destroyed. I.e.:

```
void f(int a) {
    const char* s = nullptr;
    if(a == 10) { 
        s = std::string("aaaa").c_str(); }
    // Here s may point to invalid data because
    // corresponding std::string object has been destroyed
}
```